# Function call in JavaScript with another parentheses "func()();"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to JavaScript but I started a course for building react native applications, my problem was understanding this expression in redux `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName);`

I'm just having trouble understanding this expression `functionName(params)(classname)`. What does this expression exactly means as of syntax *(I'm not trying to understand the redux side of this)* and how to use it?

Comment: This looks similar to a closure. (function(_i){ ... })(i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seem like `functionName(params)` returns a closure or another function which gets called directly, passing it the `classname` variable.